# Difference in rendering when visiting node/1 and programmatically loading it

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

A node loads a profile of a user (external database + views). All of this works when I visit: node/123/profile/id/3. Now I have implemented hook_menu() in order to load any profile page and have nicer URLs.

When I load it myself for some reason $left in page.tpl.php is suddenly empty and many more variables seem not to be loading. I have tried many different functions to render and create the correct $output but realized that node_show() seems to be the function of choice.

Testing has shown now that for some reason `hook_nodeapi()` calls are ignored.
My code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu
 */
function modulename_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['my/nice/url/profile'] = array(
    'description' => 'This page holds a view that shows profiles based on the %',
    'page callback' => 'website_profile_load',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Menu path wildcard callback
 */
function website_profile_load() {
  $output = node_show(node_load(1221), false, true);
  return $output;
}
```

So what is the correct way to do this and get Panels (see comment below) to load correctly?

### UPDATE:

I am using [table wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) and Views 2 to connect to another database with information about people that aren't users of the system. This is an alumni page, the page is administered externally and showed internally (nothing I can do about, have to make this work :)

Just discovered that Panels aren't loaded at all. So even if the node I am trying to load is uses panels for some reason none of that is loaded.

Comment: Why dont' you use the path module (in core).
Go to the Alias page /admin/build/path/add or use the PHP function path_set_alias ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be that apparently somewhere in the pipeline of creating a node Drupal uses `$path` (that is originally set by `$_GET['q']`) and sometimes also `$_GET['q']` to determine how to render the page. NOTE that I am using Panels and Ctools Page Manager modules in order to get my things working correctly.

It turns out Panels, if you search the code, looks at `$_GET['q']` for quite an amount of things.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu
 */
function modulename_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // For department and having nice URL's for their profile pages.
  $items['my/nice/url/profile/%'] = array(
    'description' => 'This page holds a view that shows profiles based on the %',
    'page callback' => 'website_profile_load',
    'page arguments' => arg(4),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Menu path callback
 */
function website_profile_load($id = NULL) {

  // Rename the query internally since other functions base the design
  // on the way the query is structured and not simply by the node which
  // is currently loading.
  if(!empty($id)) {
    $path = $_GET['q'] = 'node/1221/profile/id/' . $id;
  }

  // Use ctools function to correctly display node view since 
  // this site heavily uses ctools rendering for panels and
  // web parts / web pages.  
  drupal_load('module', 'page_manager');
  ctools_include('node_view', 'page_manager', 'plugins/tasks');

  if(function_exists('page_manager_node_view')) {
    $output = page_manager_node_view(node_load(1221));
  } else {
    // Will display incorrectly but still load the UI 
    $output = node_page_view(node_load(1221));
  }

  return $output;
}
```

And it works :)

Comment: For the record : I don't think you need page_manager, the point here is just to set the query to you nid. So you need only tehse two lines :  $_GET['q'] = 'node/1221/profile/id/' . $id; $output = node_page_view(node_load(1221));
It works at least on D6

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Menu path wildcard callback
 */
function website_profile_load($uid = null) {
  if (!$uid) {
    global $user; // if no user passed in argument, show current user profile
    $uid = $user->uid;
  }
  $output = drupal_render(content_profile_show_profiles($uid));
}
```

Comment: this assumes the site is built using http://drupal.org/project/content_profile , right!? - I had a quick look at the module and find it interesting but couldnt figure out how you got to this solution.  Could you explain a bit more please!?

Comment: actually I am not using content_profile :) but the guess wasn't to far of a fetch. I have updated the question above with the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why rendering the result of a node_load is different from going to the stock Drupal path /node. It is way too much to go over here honestly but the short answer is that you have to define a template/theme and blocks etc for each page you create. Just because you make a new path and do a node_load in the callback for that path doesn't mean Drupal can automagically know how you want to display that content. It simply loads data from the node and it is available to do whatever you please with it after that. This is why you get a blankish looking page instead of what you'd expect from going through /node.

However I will offer this simple solution since it sounds like you want the exact same page you'd get when you go to 'node/123/profile/id/3' but accessible through a link you define yourself. You just need to setup a redirect in your hook_menu like so:

```
$items['my/nice/url/profile'] = array(
'description' => 'This page holds a view that shows profiles based on the %',
'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
'page arguments' => 'node/123/profile/id/3',
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK);
```

This is essentially saying that when you navigate to 'my/nicer/url/profile' it runs: drupal_goto('node/123/profile/id/3');

Comment: Hi matt, thank you for the answer i will try that now. I am actually trying to learn more about how drupal renders the pages and have a some what good grip on node_load() and theme(). As I also understand it from the Drupal Pro Development book is that node_page_view() is actually how I would want to call it. Only, it makes no difference. I have tried theme() node_load() and node_page_view(). They all don't fit the description.

Comment: Ok I realize now, which I feared, that this wasn't the answer since it does a HTTP redirect and does not maintain the nice URL.  Which is really important to this platform.

Comment: Hmm yes I realized after I posted that this would change the URL in the navbar. You could always use JavaScript to change whats in the navbar to whatever you want after the redirect but that is a really poor solution. Here is what I would recommend, go into the core node.module and find function node_menu. Then try to figure out which of the paths corresponds to your target (node/123/profile/id/3) and then basically copy that page callback etc into your module's hook_menu. if you are trying to demystify something going on in the core, you can always just check Drupal's stock code!